# How do I provide a list of inputs for a cmdlet

Tags: powershell, office365

I want to feed a list of identities from

```
get-msoluser | select userprincipalname
```

to:

```
Set-CsOnlineDialInConferencingUser -allowpstnonlymeetings $true -Identity name@domain.com
```

But integrating these two is where I'm struggling, I'm guessing a `foreach` loop is the best approach? But I just can't get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do a `foreach-object` loop like so:

```
get-msoluser |
    select-object userprincipalname | 
        Foreach-object {
            set-csonlinedialinconferencinguser `
                -allowpstnonlymeetings $true `
                -identity $_.userprincipalname
        }
```

Comment: I suggest using splatting or keep the arguments on one line.  Escaping newlines is sloppy and mistake-prone

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 - Splatting can be helpful, especially for commands with many parameters. However, the splat will still need to be created and would probably be multiple lines. I would not find a splat that useful in this situation with only two (2) parameters which are indented appropriately.

Comment: @lit It's not about the indentation, it's about the mistake-prone nature of escaping newlines.  You use the other two methods for readability and doing so additionally avoids some editor mangling your file.  Changing formatting should not butcher your functionality (for example, add a space behind those grave accents and suddenly your script is broken)

Comment: @lit I just did it for readability. This wouldn't be the first time theincorrigible1 shared one of his best practices though :P

Comment: It's not one of *my* best practices, but a best practice shared among the professional community as a courtesy to coworker sanity.  Side-note: It's really weird that MS didn't make that parameter a switch

Comment: Indeed the editor did mangle this but I was able to switly resolve, big thank you to @ShawnEsterman, you're my hero.

Answer (score 0):

Foreach-loop is faster than foreach-object. (data stored to memory before execution)

```
$Users = get-msoluser
Foreach ($User in $Users)
{
Set-CsOnlineDialInConferencingUser -allowpstnonlymeetings $true -Identity $User.userprincipalname
}
```

Comment: It also uses more memory. So which to use is dependent on what the user wants and what their environment is like. The other difference is that you cannot pass the output from foreach directly to the pipeline. Ultimately use whicever one you feel like using until it is not the right one to use...